# Malloc occasionally returns null on Win64

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory-management, heap-memory

Disclaimer: I tag the question as both C and C++ as I use `std::malloc` in a C++ project.

My C++ application allocates/deallocates some memory repeatedly. In most cases I use `new`/`delete`, but in some of them (custom containers) I use `std::malloc`. Operator `new` never returns nullptr or throws `bad_alloc`, but `std::malloc` return nullptr occasionally on some machines.

For now we build for Win64 only, and the vast majority of users use Windows 10.

What the reason can be?

- I exclude physical memory depletion, as the application allocates less than 3 Gb of memory, and those machines have 8-16 Gb + swap.
- Malloc argument is always greater than zero and less than 256 Mb. It's verified with assertions.
- Hypothesis 1: can it be address space exhaustion due to fragmentation? Small buffer reallocations in the application may occur many times a second, but their sizes are usually a few kilobytes.
- Hypothesis 2: can it be a memory corruption due to a bug in the application? Does Windows store some heap service information in application-accessible memory, where the application can overwrite it without crashing by access violation? Could you please provide some links to Windows heap management explanation.

P.S. I use the default heap only, no custom-allocated WinAPI heaps.

Comment: Hypothesis 1 can be ruled out on 64-bit machines. Hypothesis 2 may be possible, but it is extremely unlikely that such a specific corruption occurs; Your process is thousands of times more likely to crash.

Comment: When you say "assertions" do you mean the [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) macro which is not doing anything in typical release builds?

Comment: @Ctx Why could hypothesis 1 be ruled out? Even if the virtual address space on a 64-bit system is unlikely to run out, the actual physical address space could become fragmented enough to lead to allocation problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, I misread your comment; no, fragmentation of the physical address space cannot lead to allocation problems. The addresses are mapped on page granularity.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, I mean a custom alternative to `assert`, which is definitely enabled in release builds. At least, it helped to catch a zero-argument bug once.

Comment: Double check that you use unsigned and preferably size_t types for your malloc bytes and assert check. Strange things happen if you get multiplication overflow into negative numbers, for example.